# Object-c/iOS :About use NSUserDefaults set serial numbers/password

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist, record

I got many issues about setting sn/pwd

Because the first default data is from URL

got a plist data like this:

```
{
   serial_number=1234;
   password = 7777;
}
```

The application finish launched,It will download from URL via the code like this

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"http://getdefaults.php"];
NSArray *plistData;
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURLURLWithString:urlString]
                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                         timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil]; 
 NSString *listFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnDataencoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[listFile dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
plistData = [listFile propertyList];
```

At first , I try to create a plist data in iphone:

```
NSArray *localPaths   = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *localDocPath    = [localPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *localFilePath   = [localDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"InputPassword.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *localDictread  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:localFilePath];
```

Than I compare with the information I get

```
if(localDictread==nil){
   //pop a textfield to let user enter the serial numbers and password
   //if the text in the textfield is equal the default SN/PWD from plistData,write the sn/pwd to plist in iphone
}
```

But I found `NSUserDefaults` , Can it work as the same ?

I mean work as the same is can I record a serial number and password in my iphone ???

What is best way to record a user serial number/password in iphone ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are a storing password, not NSUserDefaults nor serializing the data in NSDocumentDirectory are great solutions because data is stored with little protection. iOS provides the [KeyChain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) mechanism for this porupose. It provides C interfaces that are a bit obscure, but a Buzz Andersen got a nice [Objective-C interface](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security) going called SFHFKeychainUtils. With SFHFKeychainUtils you can do something like:

```
[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:user.text andPassword:pass.text forServiceName:@"my_service" updateExisting:YES error:nil];
```

And that gets stored securely into the keychain. To recover the password:

```
NSString *pw = [SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:user.text andServiceName:@"my_service"
```